# Xml parsing Media tag values not getting in android?

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I am implement xml parsing but when i access media tag at that time images values is not displaying.i have implement this check below code is not working for media id and url.you can check xml data in below image

[image]

```
public static final String X_PF_CONTENT_IMPORT="pf_content_import";
    public static final String X_SPOT="spot";
    public static final String X_ID="id";
        public static final String X_VALID="valid";
        public static final String X_TEXT="text";
            public static final String X_HEADER="header";
            public static final String X_BODY="body";
        public static final String X_MEDIA="media";
            public static final String X_IMAGE="image"; 

XmlParsing xparser= new XmlParsing();           
            String xml = xparser.getXmlFromUrl(url); // getting XML
            Document doc = xparser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element   
            NodeList nspot = doc.getElementsByTagName(X_SPOT);
            Log.e("Nodename","--->"+nspot.getLength());
            for(int i=0;i<nspot.getLength();i++){
                    Node n=nspot.item(i);
                    Element eLemenSpot = (Element)n;
                    String id=eLemenSpot.getAttribute(X_ID);
                    String valid=eLemenSpot.getElementsByTagName(X_VALID).item(0).getTextContent();
                    Log.e("Id","--->"+id);
                    Log.e("Valid","--->"+valid);

                    NodeList text=eLemenSpot.getElementsByTagName(X_TEXT);

                    Node ntext=text.item(0);
                    Element elementText=(Element)ntext;
                    String header=elementText.getElementsByTagName(X_HEADER).item(0).getTextContent();
                    String body=elementText.getElementsByTagName(X_BODY).item(0).getTextContent();

                    Log.e("Header","--->"+header);
                    Log.e("Body","--->"+body);

                    NodeList media=eLemenSpot.getElementsByTagName(X_MEDIA);
                    for(int k=0;k<media.getLength();k++){
                        Node nmedia=media.item(k);
                        Element elementMedia=(Element)nmedia;
                        String image_id=elementMedia.getAttribute("id");
                        String image_url=elementMedia.getElementsByTagName(X_IMAGE).item(k).getTextContent();
                        Log.e(" Media Id", "---->"+image_id);
                        Log.e("Media Url", "---->"+image_url);
                    }

            }
```

> Logcat

```
03-05 00:36:11.513: E/Nodename(14195): --->2
03-05 00:36:11.513: E/Id(14195): --->1
03-05 00:36:11.513: E/Valid(14195): --->2015-03-05T11:34:59.337278+01:00
03-05 00:36:11.523: E/Header(14195): --->OPTISCH GANZ VERÃNDERT
03-05 00:36:11.523: E/Body(14195): --->BACK TO THE ROOTS: MANDY CAPRISTO PUNKTET MIT DUNKLEN HAAREN
03-05 00:36:11.523: E/Media Id(14195): ---->
03-05 00:36:11.523: E/Media Url(14195): ---->http://content3.promiflash.de/article-images/infoscreen1/mandy-capristo-mit-dunklen-haaren.jpg
03-05 00:36:11.523: E/Id(14195): --->2
03-05 00:36:11.523: E/Valid(14195): --->2015-03-05T11:34:59.337278+01:00
03-05 00:36:11.523: E/Header(14195): --->OPTISCH GANZ VERÃNDERT
03-05 00:36:11.523: E/Body(14195): --->BACK TO THE ROOTS: MANDY CAPRISTO PUNKTET MIT DUNKLEN HAAREN
03-05 00:36:11.533: E/Media Id(14195): ---->
03-05 00:36:11.533: E/Media Url(14195): ---->http://content3.promiflash.de/article-images/infoscreen2/mandy-capristo-mit-dunklen-haaren.jpg
```

Comment: i want access media tag image id and image url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this

```
NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("image");
for(int i=0,size= nodeList.getLength(); i<size; i++) {
     Log.e("",nodeList.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("id").getNodeValue());
     Log.i("",nodeList.item(i).getTextContent());
}
```

Comment: no not working this is getting tag multiple times also url not display check this http://pastie.org/9998863

Answer (score 0):

i need to create imagenode list

```
NodeList media=eLemenSpot.getElementsByTagName(X_MEDIA);
                for(int k=0;k<media.getLength();k++){
                    Node nmedia=media.item(k);
                    Element elementMedia=(Element)nmedia;
                    NodeList nimage=elementMedia.getElementsByTagName(X_IMAGE);
                    for(int j=0;j<nimage.getLength();j++){
                        Log.e(" Media Id", "---->"+nimage.item(j).getAttributes().getNamedItem(X_ID).getNodeValue());
                        Log.e("Media Url", "---->"+nimage.item(j).getTextContent());

                    }
                }
```

Comment: this is as same as my answer